# Is there a distinction between Windows 10 and Windows 10S apps on Microsoft Store?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

Without going into too much background detail, I'm maintaining a Win 10 app which gets deployed to the Microsoft Store.

The latest release failed Microsoft's QA. In the QA report, it mentions "Tested Devices: (Win 10 S) Microsoft Surface Laptop."  Since I don't maintain our build/submit process, I emailed the person in charge about the problem and the Microsoft QA notes.  He replied, "Don't worry about it. We don't build for 10S" and then promptly went on a month long sabbatical.

Now I'm charged with finding out what is happening.  I've looked through a lot of the documentation on building for UWP and Microsoft Store, but I've never seen any mention of differences for 10/10S apps.

The first question I need to answer (to my manager) is if there are indeed any differences, or are all Microsoft Store apps the same?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/will-linux-distros-run-on-windows-10-s/

Comment: If I am not mistaken, there are some best/mandatory practices for Win 10S apps, but I don’t remember where to check for them.  Sorry.

Comment: The big difference between Windows 10 S and any other version of Windows 10 is that 10 S can only run applications downloaded from the Windows Store. Every other version of Windows 10 has the option to install applications from third-party sites and stores, as has the majority of versions of Windows before it.Windows 10 S will also come with Microsoft’s BitLocker encryption system for securing your files in case of theft.